# certificate has expired error whilst running heroku commands

Tags: heroku, django-cms, heroku-cli

I'm trying to do the following with my hosted app on Heroku-

- create a database backup
- download the database backup
- Restore the backup in a local postgres database
  However, I get stuck in the first step itself. Running the below command throws the following error -

  heroku pg:backups:capture -a app-name
  CERT_HAS_EXPIRED: certificate has expired

I even tried running the following command, however, that did not help either -

```
heroku run:detached pg:backups capture –a app-name
Running pg:backups:capture on ⬢ app-name... done, run.1879 (Free)
Run heroku logs --app app-name --dyno run.1879 to view the output.

(env) E:\new_website\>heroku logs --app app-name --dyno run.1879
2021-10-29T05:18:36.001962+00:00 heroku[run.1879]: Starting process with command pg:backups:capture
2021-10-29T05:18:36.564987+00:00 heroku[run.1879]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-29T05:18:36.953570+00:00 app[run.1879]: bash: pg:backups:capture: command not found
2021-10-29T05:18:37.068925+00:00 heroku[run.1879]: Process exited with status 127
2021-10-29T05:18:37.103435+00:00 heroku[run.1879]: State changed from up to complete
```

Finally, I also tried using the HEROKU_DEBUG environment variable to see what the real error was -

```
(env) E:\new_website\>SET HEROKU_DEBUG=1

(env) E:\new_website\>heroku pg:backups:capture --app app-name
Adding the following trusted certificate authorities
E:\ap01\Ruby\cacert.pem
--> POST /actions/addon-attachments/resolve
--> {"app":"neevista-web","addon_attachment":"DATABASE_URL","addon_service":"heroku-postgresql"}
<-- 200 OK
<-- [{"addon":{"id":"9ccc7a6d-8001-473a-8ef1-e24614ad26c0","name":"postgresql-curly-92807","app":{"id":"587ec79f-3989-40eb-bceb-17220824a275","name":"app-name"},"plan":{"id":"062a1cc7-f79f-404c-9f91-135f70175577","name":"heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"}},"app":{"id":"587ec79f-3989-40eb-bceb-17220824a275","name":"app-name"},"id":"5a2ba589-22e6-4c42-a3bd-d634b4581eb5","name":"DATABASE","namespace":null,"created_at":"2021-06-21T15:05:48Z","updated_at":"2021-06-21T15:05:48Z","web_url":"https://addons-sso.heroku.com/apps/587ec79f-3989-40eb-bceb-17220824a275/addons/9ccc7a6d-8001-473a-8ef1-e24614ad26c0","log_input_url":null,"config_vars":["DATABASE_URL"]}]
Adding the following trusted certificate authorities
E:\ap01\Ruby\cacert.pem
--> GET /client/v11/databases/9ccc7a6d-8001-473a-8ef1-e24614ad26c0
! CERT_HAS_EXPIRED: certificate has expired
Error: certificate has expired
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1502:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:711:12)
```

I've tried updating Heroku CLI, restarting the Heroku app but nothing has helped. Not sure if this helps but I've two versions (9 and 13) of Postgresql running on this windows machine and my app is trying the use the version 13.

Could you please advise what I'm doing wrong here or if there is an ongoing issue at your end?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out myself after Heroku support failed to assist as they classified the issue as a local problem.
For some reason, I'd setup `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable previously. This environment variable was pointing to a certificate pem file -> `E:\ap01\Ruby\cacert.pem`

After deleting this environment variable heroku commands started to work again.